# Xmonad doesn't change workspace

Tags: xmonad, workspaces

I have just installed xmonad. I logged in, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, and got a xterm.
(Pressed again to see windows tiling.)

Typed in man xmonad, read, press <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> to switch between windows, ok, then press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>... And it doesn't switch between workspaces...

As it is the first time I execute xmonad, is there any key binding that I might check or fix ? Do I have to set a number of workspace, maybe it is set internally to 1. What can be the cause of my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your user informations, you live in France, so I assume that you use an AZERTY keyboard. XMonad default configuration is made for QWERTY keyboards which have direct access to numbers, while you have to use shift to access them on a french AZERTY keyboard.

[XMonad.Config.Azerty](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Config-Azerty.html) fixes this by remapping the key to the corresponding characters. To use it, import the module and replace `defaultConfig` with `azertyConfig`.